# Use CSS and JS client files linked to html with express app on zeit-now

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, vercel

I have an simple Express application defining routes for an html file in my public folder. In this index.html file i have linked my css and js file which are in the same folder. When i use npm start it works without any problem but when i publish it on zeit-now i get error 404 for js file and *"Refused to apply style from 'https://test.julienmerasli.now.sh/public/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled." for css file.* 
Here is my deployment : https://test.julienmerasli.now.sh/ 
Here is my project: https://gitlab.com/chaudoinblazin/test-zeit-now-css

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code - I think the problem is with the paths you used to reference the css and js files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/index.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="buttonClicked()">This is a button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The files served from the `public` folder will be available from your root of the website so e.g. https://test.julienmerasli.now.sh. Right now though your html will look for the css and js files in https://test.julienmerasli.now.sh/public.

So inside the html you just have to remove the `public` part on the `href` and `src` paths and this should work.

Not sure what you're trying to build but if you just wanna serve some static or simple API files, you might not need Express. Check out this [migration guide](https://zeit.co/guides/migrate-to-zeit-now/) for a good intro.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't seem to work. I finally found the solution for the css by adding `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/")));` to my server.js, but my js files are still not found. The only solution i found for the moment is to add 
app.get("/public/index.js", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.js");
}); but if i had to do it for every file it will be problematic, so i still search for a better solution. Then, if you want to know, i then want to do an express passport socket.io application so i don't think i can do it differently

Comment: Still not sure if I understand what exactly you wanna do but you could still serve the static files in the regular way: https://zeit.co/docs/builders#official-builders/static. Additionally you could check if routing maybe easier to configure with a `now.json` config file: https://zeit.co/docs/v2/advanced/configuration/